# Custom CSS does not apply to Body element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My custom CSS does not apply the Body element and when my page loads, most of the elements are overridden by the jQuery CSS. If I do not put jQuery CSS, it adds a `'Div'` tag at the end of the page with the text `'loading'`.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="rssFeedLoad">Loadin...</p>
<p id="rssFeed"> </p>
<script>
//debugger;
var yQuery = 'http://news.google.com/news?geo=SOMEZIP&output=rss';
var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent("select * from xml where url='" + yQuery + "'") + '&format=json&callback=?';
//debugger;
(function(){
    //debugger;
    $.getJSON(yql)
         .done(function(data){
        //debugger;
        var rssFeed = document.getElementById("rssFeed");
        $.each(data.query.results.rss.channel.item, function(i,item){
            var rssLink = document.createElement("a");
            rssLink.id = 'news' + i;
            rssLink.href = item.link;
            rssLink.innerText = item.title;
            rssFeed.appendChild(rssLink);
            var br = document.createElement("br");
            rssFeed.appendChild(br);
        });
        linkify( 'a' );
     });
})();
//debugger;
var supports3DTransforms =  document.body.style['webkitPerspective'] !== undefined || 
                            document.body.style['MozPerspective'] !== undefined;
//debugger;
function linkify( selector ) {
    if( supports3DTransforms ) {

        var nodes = document.querySelectorAll( selector );

        for( var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++ ) {
            var node = nodes[i];

            if( !node.className || !node.className.match( /roll/g ) ) {
                node.className += ' roll';
                node.innerHTML = '<span data-title="'+ node.text +'">' + node.innerHTML + '</span>';
            }
        };
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Custom CSS has the following definition for `Body` element. I also have other styles for an `a` element and those are applied to the links. As of now, its just my `Body` element styles which do not work.

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #333 !important;
    color: #eee;
}
```

When I check with the Chrome Dev tools, I notice that my custom Background style has been overridden (I see them as stricken through).

I searched through StackOverFlow and other forums for this problem and found following three solutions:

- Add `data-role="none"` to the elements. I tried this as well, however, this does not work. At least with the Body element it seems.
- List the custom CSS AFTER the jQuery CSS in the `Head` element. Which I am already doing
  it. Currently not working.
- Add `!important` to the style properties of the Body (in my example I am showing it only for one). I tried to add it on all three properties, but none worked.

I am not sure if I am missing anything here (may be a syntax error?). I am pretty new to the front-end techs. So pardon my any silly mistake here. I am just following various tutorials/examples to learn. Any help here is appreciated.

Regards,
Rumit

Comment: Would you mind creating a JSFiddle? Would make debugging this much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

over your body there is a `div`. you must style that `div` like this:

```
div[data-role="page"] {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #333 !important;
    color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: Mohsen, Thank you very much. As soon as 3 minutes are over, I will mark this as an answer :). However, I am new to this stuff. So just want to understand the answer better. Could you elaborate little further, what 'div' you are referring here? Why not body[data-role="page"] ? Why does it work directly for links (<a>) without putting any data-role? This will help better understand the problem and it may help down the line.

Comment: with amazing inspect-element in chrome you can see what i see :), there is a `div` after body with `data-role="page"` attribute and you must select a `div` with this attribute, not `body`